# Using Text Functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using LEFT, UCASE, MID and a few other text functions.
eg `If UCase(Mid(VBAFormField, 4, 3)) = "ABC" Then`

For most users the code works fine. On one PC it gives an error and seems to need modification.
eg `If UCase(Application.Worksheetfunction.Mid(VBAFormField, 4, 3)) = "ABC" Then`

Things I tried:

1. Excel versions are identical
2. VBA Reference libraries are the same on both computers

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `VbaFormField`?

Comment: What if you just use Mid() and not `Application.Worksheetfunction.Mid()`  ?  Is there a reason you're using that one?

Comment: For clarification
I understand that MID is a VBA function and also a worksheet function.  So it can written as:
1. Mid(....)
2. VBA.Mid(...)
3. Applicaion.Worksheet.Mid(...)
I just thought the first option was the most efficient code (and it works on most PCs).  But on the problem PC option 1 does not work and options 2 and 3 will fix the issue.

Comment: VBAFormField is simply a text variable

Comment: What is the exact error you get?  If it's "can't find project or library" then it's likely a missing project reference.

Comment: Yes it's "can't find project or library" .  However on checking the VBA libraries they are the same on both PCs.  Weird?

Comment: The `Mid` error is a red herring, as covered by @Variatus below. Check all you project references for one marked as "missing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess there must be an add-on or a language setting that is causing a conflict. However as Tim Williams pointed out, you're using the worksheet function in VBA when a VBA function exists that does this exact task you need to complete it.

While probably not necessary, you could go even further and scope the formulas to be vba specific just to ensure the proper library is being utilized.

```
MsgBox VBA.UCase(VBA.Mid("SomeText!", 4, 3))
```

Comment: For clarification I understand that MID is a VBA function and also a worksheet function. So it can written as: 1. Mid(....) 2. VBA.Mid(...) 3. Applicaion.Worksheet.Mid(...) I just thought the first option was the most efficient code (and it works on most PCs).

Adding VBA.  or  Application.Worksheet.  will make the code run on the problematic PC. I guess I wanted to know why??

Answer (score 1):

I have frequently experienced that VBA (2010) will highlight a missing library for an item for which the library is ***not*** missing because another library in fact ***is*** missing. It's usually just the first reference to any library in the code. So you should look for a missing library further down in the code, more likely, a not so standard object.

I have also frequently experienced (with any version of VBA up to 365) that errors aren't shown right away but are "remembered". I have explained this to myself by acknowledging that given a large project VBA will assemble the parts it needs as it needs them but once an error was discovered it won't be overlooked a second time and is flagged right away. This behavior could explain why only one of your PCs objects to the code. The others just didn't get around to it yet.